# pipes vs. redirects

Tags: linux, input

I've been using pipes and redirects for a long time and just realized that I don't know exactly how they are different. I just know that if you want to store the output in a file, then you use >. Otherwise most of the time you just use |. Can someone explain the difference between pipes and redirects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is backwards redirection the same as a pipe?](http://superuser.com/questions/277680/is-backwards-redirection-the-same-as-a-pipe)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The both do the same basic thing; they redirect a file descriptor of the process executed. The difference lies in how. A pipe connects the stdout of one process to the stdin of another, whereas redirection redirects from/to a file (`>` from stdout to a file, `<` from a file to stdin).

Comment: The distinction sort of blurs in Linux and other systems that have `/dev/fd`. For example, if you run `echo foo > >(somecommand)`, it will expand to `echo foo > /dev/fd/3`. It's still redirection, but to a process.