# Is backwards redirection the same as a pipe?

Tags: linux, redirection, pipe

In Linux if you type

```
sort < txtfile
```

is that the same thing as

```
cat txtfile | sort
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To your title question: No. Getting `stdin` from file contents (*input redirection*) is not the same as piping one program's output to another program's input.

But, as your `cat` actually just prints a file's contents, the result is effectively the same in that example.

---

But even just the following produce very different results:

```
$ cat * | sort
$ sort < *
```

If there's more than one matching file, the latter will produce

```
-bash: *: ambiguous redirect
```

since it's just not as flexible as the former, which will cat all matching files, and pipe them as input into `sort`.

Comment: What about... `sort *`? No useless use of cat, no useless use of indirection, shortest to type, easiest to think of, **and** I believe GNU sort will treat you to scalability optimizations for very large files (not so sure about that - half remembering something there)

Comment: @sehe Probably. I just used the example to show the two are different. This isn't about efficient use of sort. Sort is more flexible thn that though, sure.

Comment: @DanielBeck, Regarding efficiency, is `sort < txtfile` much more efficient than `cat txtfile | sort`?