# How to overwrite file using echo?

Tags: linux, bash

When using `echo "foo">> bar.txt` more than once it appends to the end of a file. How to overwrite `bar.txt` each time?

Comment: Dennis' answer is correct. See `man bash` and search (using `/`) for the section on "REDIRECTION". Specifically subsections "Redirecting Output" and "Appending Redirected Output".

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`>` is for redirecting to a file (overwriting it), while `>>` is for appending.

To overwrite `bar.txt`, use this:

```
echo "foo" > bar.txt
```

Comment: More commonly, `>` is referred to as **redirecting** (standard output to a file) whilst the pipe symbol  `|` is referred to as **piping** (standard output to another process). You run the risk of confusing people like me when you refer to `>` as 'piping'

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I've seen **piping** in a few books (and I've been saying it for years), but **redirecting** seems to be far more common. Thanks.

Comment: @Dennis Piping is using the pipe `|` for connecting the output of one program/command to the input of another. [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/277680/is-backwards-redirection-the-same-as-a-pipe).

Comment: @DanielBeck: I meant I saw **piping to a file**. Example: [Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches - Piping to a file or printer](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781617290213/the-pipeline-connecting-commands/ch04lev1sec3)

Comment: Note that according to page 43, in PowerShell `> foo` is just syntactic sugar for `| Out-File foo`, and therefore is a form of piping ;-)